# Child selector deprecated

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the new proper way to use a child selector with a context node in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406642/what-is-the-new-proper-way-to-use-a-child-selector-with-a-context-node-in-jquery)

From the jQuery docs:

> Note: The $("> elem", context) selector will be deprecated in a future release. Its usage is thus discouraged in lieu of using alternative selectors.

http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

What would be an `alternative selector` for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(context).children('elem')
```

also `$("> elem", context)` is deprecated, but `$(context+" >elem")` and `$("parent>child")` are not

Answer (score 1):

```
$('parent').children('childrenelements')
```

Is my guess :)

But as the other poster said, its only searching directly for childs in a context.

Comment: That's what I want hence the direct child selector `>`

Answer (score 1):

For example, if the context is an element, you would use the selector for that element instead of specifying it as context. So instead of:

```
var main = $('#Main');
var mainDivs = $('> div', main);
```

you could use:

```
var mainDivs = $('#Main > div');
```

Comment: That would work except the fact that I'm working with a jQuery object as 'parent' / 'context'.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across the same issue, I was in the middle of a function and none of the above really helped me. .find seemed to do the trick. This is an example oif how it was useful:

```
$('selectedcontext').first(function(){
    // perform operations on selectedcontext for ex:
    if($(this).hasClass('someclass')){
        $(this).find('textarea').val();
    }
});
```

Comment: This isn't the same as doing `$("> elem", context)`. Because your codes does it check for all descendants of the element and not just the direct descendants.