# What is the new proper way to use a child selector with a context node in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

In the [jQuery documentation for the child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) I saw this note:

> Note: The `$("> elem", context)` selector will be deprecated in a future release. Its usage is thus discouraged in lieu of using alternative selectors.

I use this pattern all the time, usually like this:

```
$nodes.find('> children[something=morecomplicated] > somethingelse');
```

However, I don't understand what the "alternative selectors" they refer to could be. **What is the right way to write a selector which traverses the immediate children of a context node?**  As a bonus, can anyone explain *why* this is depreciated? All the alternatives everyone is giving seem amazingly *ugly*.

Here are some things that *don't* work:

```
// does not guarantee that '.child' is an immediate child
$nodes.find('.child > .grandchild');

// this will return empty array in recent jQuery
// and will return full list of children in older jQuery
$nodes.children('.child > .grandchild');

// Anything like this which forces you to split up the selector.
// This is ugly and inconsistent with usual selector ease-of-use,
// and is a non-trivial conversion for long or complex selectors.
$nodes.children('.child').children('.grandchild');
// After all, no one would ever recommend
$nodes.find('.this').children('.that');
// instead of
$nodes.find('.this > .that');
```

Comment: See here for additional information:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833558/child-selector-deprecated

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that question even after diligent searching. None of the answers are really very satisfactory, though.

Comment: You definitely raise a good point. But, unless you discover something I'm not currently aware of, I think chaining children calls and splitting up the selector is probably your only option.

Comment: That is terrible. Does anyone know the rationale behind depreciating the use of an initial '>'? I may want to take the fight to jQuery.

Comment: Wait, they certainly _haven't_ deprecated the use of an initial '>'. As I said in my answer: they have just deprecated the use of the comma followed by context selector. So this http://jsfiddle.net/DwUTw/ remains to be perfectly fine. I think we all just got a little bit confused.

Comment: Really? No other selector documentation page has this depreciation warning, and the [jQuery Core documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) makes no mention of the context parameter being depreciated. Maybe I don't even understand the depreciation notice!

Comment: The context parameter being deprecated is certainly the way I interpret that warning message. As it is a plan for future deprecation, maybe that is why it is not yet in the documentation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason they are saying:

> Note: The `$("> elem", context)` selector will be deprecated in a future release. Its usage is thus discouraged in lieu of using alternative selectors.

Is due to the comma followed by the context in the selector. E.g. `$("> elem")` is fine however, `$("> elem", context)` will be deprecated.

**`$("> elem", context)` is the same as `$(context + "> elem")`.**

A correct way of obtaining children and grandchildren is

```
$("elem").children('.child').children('.grandchild');
```

or

```
context.children('.child').children('.grandchild');
```

or

```
context.find('> .child > .grandchild');
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with the suggested alternatives, but I have to comment on the reasoning given. The whole point of `> elem` is that it assumes some sort of context. `$("> elem")` would not be fine, in fact, it would be meaningless, because what exactly is `elem` being related to? And `$(context + "> elem")` would only work if `context` were a selector string.

Comment: Actually, I'm not entirely sure if they really meant to say that the use of a context argument with a relative selector is deprecated, or that the relative selector syntax itself is deprecated. To make matters worse, ever since jQuery's docs were completely redesigned, the deprecation notice has all but vanished. I'm almost tempted to create a new question for this reason.