# select elements using display:block

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

This is the html content from which I want to select all elements inside report having display block using jQuery
`$("#report:visible")` does not work for me.

```
<div id="report">
        <div id="p1" style="display: block;">
            <input id="pname1"  type="checkbox" name="report1">
            <input id="pname2"  type="checkbox" name="report2">
        </div>
        <div id="p2"  style="display: none;">
            <input id="pname1"  type="checkbox" name="report1">
            <input id="pname2"  type="checkbox" name="report2">
        </div>
        <div id="p3"  style="display: none;">
            <input id="pname1"  type="checkbox" name="report1">
            <input id="pname2"  type="checkbox" name="report2">
        </div>
            <div id="p4"  style="display: block;">
            <input id="pname3"  type="checkbox" name="report1">
            <input id="pname4"  type="checkbox" name="report2">
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tired `$('#report').css('display') == 'block';`?

Comment: Use a class to set `display: block` then select by that class.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Maybe you can use this piece of jQuery :

```
$("#report div:visible").each(function() { 
    console.log($(this).attr('id')); 
});
```

Or this one :) ?

```
$("#report div:visible");
```

Comment: Careful, if elements inside invisible tab or something, its better to check css styles manually, as "visible" will not select those elements

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#report > :visible")
```

This will select the direct children of `#report` that are visible. Without the space you're selecting `#report` itself if it's visible. (Without the `>` it'd target also the inputs.)

Comment: I thought child selection with `>` was now deprecated in favour of `.children()`. Or was the deprecation rescinded?

Comment: I don't see any mention of that in the docs (http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/).

Comment: If the deprecation is still in force, then it must be buried away in some other part of the documentation, not where it should be.

Comment: My bad, a [particular use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406642/) of `>` was deprecated and now gets no mention in the documentation. Your code is fine though I think I would use `$("#report").children("div").is(":visible")`.

Answer (score 2):

This may help you with several selectors [CSS Selectors](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/).

As for your requirement, You can use this to select all `div` with `display:block` under the `#report`.

```
$('#report div[style*=display:block]')
```

Comment: i would not use that be cause you can't be sure it is `display:block` could also be `display: block`

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
$("[style='display: block;']");
```

but I wouldn't, I'd add a class as well to hook onto.

Comment: wouldn't this only work if `display: block;` is set directly to the element. and only if just the `display: block;` is set ?

Comment: Yep. Also, only if there is a space, not sure if JS normalises that or not. This is a terrible way to do it, a class would be better.

Comment: If you are doing based on a style property, I would use a contains selector (*=)
This would make the above syntax read 
`$("[style*='display: block;']")`, also as already mentioned, you'll have to consider the space after the colon`:` and also note I skipped the ending semicolon `;`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly select elements in CSS using a property value itself. You can however select by class. The best solution would be to use a class to assign `display: block` (such as a `visible` class) and then to select based on its presence or lack thereof.

The other way to do this is to select using the entire value of the `style` element. But the problem with this is that if you add other inline styles that selector will no longer work. You could then get into regex parsing the style attribute but in my opinion applying a `visible` or `hidden` class is far easier and will perform significantly better.

Note that another advantage of using the `visible` or `hidden` class is that you can turn it on and off with JavaScript very easily:

```
document.getElementById("id").classList.toggle("hidden");
```

Comment: Even if you can't do it in CSS you can do it with jQuery selectors.

Comment: I suppose I interpreted the question differently. Given that the title asks about selecting where `display: block` is applied, I assumed the question was more oriented to selecting based on the attribute and not the visibility. If he had an element that was visible where `display: block` was not applied (perhaps another `display` value, or none at all), I assumed that he would not want to select this. Indeed jQuery's `:visible` would work **if** the goal is visible elements and not selecting by that particular value.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```
$('#report div:visible');
```

if markup stays like that it will work. If not just add a class to the report entries like 'entry' then do

```
$('#report .entry:visible');
```

Comment: What is the different between your answer and accepted answer?!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$("#report *").filter(function(){
    $(this).css("display") === "block";
});
```

The * selects all elements within the #report. You're then filtering them to those with CSS property set to block.

Answer (score 0):

Use `:visible` in place of `[style*="display:block"]` as it will work in all browsers including IE. `[style*="display:block"]` will not work in IE.

Answer (score 0):

I like the answer by [jjj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/502381/jjj), that is using the `:visible` in the selector. However, If you really need to use the style attribute, I would use the following selector

```
$("[style*='display: block'], [style*='display:block']")
```

Please notice that

1. I used the contains operator (*=), in case any other styles were also present.
2. I omitted the ending semicolon `;` in case the style attribute was written without it.
3. Lastly, I used two selectors, separated by a comma `,` the difference is in the space after the colon `:`.

Having said that, if you know the exact style syntax written in the `style` attribute, for the `property` in question (in this case it is `display`) you can simply use it with contains `*=` or even exact match `=`.

For more visit [W3School CSS Attribute Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp)