# Sending a div to separate page for printing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am working on a website that will have a lot of recipes. I want to have a button that sends whatever recipe is being displayed to that page for printing. However, the way I have each page set up is making this complicated. I have a page for each type and have the recipes displayed via the use of divs and javascript. You click a recipe from a list and that calls a function to make the corresponding recipe go from 'none' to 'block'. Here is my current code

```
$('.main').each(function() {
    if(style.display=="block"){
    var divData = $('.card').html();
    window.location.href = "print.html";
    document.write(divData);
    }

});
```

How can I alter this code so it calls in the one that has its display set to "block"?

Comment: Instead of trying to find an element by an inline style, set a class on it (that does the styling) and select the element by that class.  Unless I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: Unfortunately can't comment just yet, but I found this on another question for basically what you're needing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14398444/select-elements-using-displayblock

Comment: make a form and specify the attribute action the page you desire to navigate when you press the button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try using a print stylesheet based on the active recipe class.

Here's more info about print stylesheets

https://css-tricks.com/print-stylesheet-approaches-blacklist-vs-whitelist/