# Can I use JQuery selectors to select from a particular node object?

Tags: jquery

In one of my textbox event handlers I determine the parent node of the current textbox by:

```
var parent = this.parentNode
```

Now I'm curious if I can use this parent node object and select all children of parent with a certain class, "c" in the string selector ".c" in a convenient way. It would be particularly nice in the case that the parent node has no id attribute.

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: `parent.childNodes` or `parent.children` comes to mind, then filter on class, or just use jQuery to start with, as that is what you've tagged the question with.

Comment: I'm going to be such a reputation pimp asking questions about popular topics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can search `selector` in `parent` context `$('>.c',$(parent))`

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/donce17/857q6/6/)

[more info about jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1)

[jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

[jQuery selector >](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

Comment: Without any explination - how do you expect people to know what exactly is happening here? I do not feel that this is a useful answer.

Comment: It's not so bad, intellisense tells me the second argument is the jquery context node which is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @IBC - That's what I'm saying. What's lacking from this answer is the information that your IDE provides. What's happening here is context manipulation - which is not obvious at all and could cause problems for people making copy pasta - which is what this answer encourages. No explanations - just the code - copy it into your work. And that doesn't make the internet a better place at all.

Comment: Maybe you could fix it for him?

Comment: @nzn - now you have a great answer :)

Comment: @Lix - I my opinion it's not great at all, the [direct children](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406642/what-is-the-new-proper-way-to-use-a-child-selector-with-a-context-node-in-jquery) selector used that way is deprecated, and why on earth would you double wrap the context part, it's plain wrong ?

Comment: @adeneo did you look in to links in my answer? where did you found that is deprecated? in 2 years old answer?

Comment: It's been deprecated for some time, so the deprecation notice has been removed, just stating that it's deprecated, and you don't have to wrap the parent for context.

Answer (score 4):

Search for the selector that you want using the following code.

```
$('>.c',$(parent))
```

Answer (score 3):

All you'll have to do is wrap the object in the jQuery syntax:

```
var parent = this.parentNode
var jquery_parent = $( parent );
```

Now you can use the parent as another jQuery object and search though it's children:

```
jquery_parent.children( ".some_class" );
// or
// $( parent ).find( ".some_class" );
```