# jQuery optimization .find() vs. .children() for nested elements - anchoring the query start to direct children

Tags: jquery, performance, children

I'm trying to match something like

```
<a>
    <b>
        <c>
            <d>
    <b>
        <c>
            <d>
</a>
```

with

```
$("a").find("d")
```

which I want to optimize by specifying the full path as

```
$("a").find("b > c > d")
```

But that still has to traverse the whole tree.
I want to tell jQuery that `<b>` is right under `<a>`.
So I've tried

```
$("a").children("b > c > d")
```

That doesn't work.
The solutions seems to be

```
$("a").children("b").children("c").children("d")
```

Is there some variant of `.find()` / `.children()` which would behave as I expected for `.children()`?
Or some "anchor" for the query string saying that the first element in the query is level 1 child?

Comment: Have you tried `$('a > b')`, or `$('a > b > c > d')`? It's not clear exactly which element you're trying to target.

Comment: There's no reason to do that, jQuery generally figures out the most efficient route, and if you really want more speed, you'd use plain JS instead.

Comment: It should also be noted that jQuery reads string selectors from right to left, and in modern browsers selectors that can be parsed by `querySelector` are just passed along to the built in methods.

Comment: I can't use `$('a > b')` as I need to do something with `<a>` before and after the children.

Comment: @adeneo Would you mind sharing a link to the explanation of "most efficient route"? And are you sure it processes the selectors right to left in all cases?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that `.find()` accepts

```
$(this).find(" > a > b > c > d")`
```

I *assume* that it could be internally doing what I want, because the resulting query duration is shorter.

Comment: And that's how you generally don't [want to do this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406642/what-is-the-new-proper-way-to-use-a-child-selector-with-a-context-node-in-jquery)