# How to replace .context jquery deprecated?

Tags: jquery, deprecated

I am facing an issue with a menu system. I found out what was possibly wrong with using a deprecated jQuery context selector, but it's impossible for me to understand this code and trying to fix it.

I have seen [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406642/what-is-the-new-proper-way-to-use-a-child-selector-with-a-context-node-in-jquery) talking about it, but as I am not a jQuery user I didn't manage to adapt this answer to my case. Any help would be appreciated!

Here is the jQuery code related to my issue. The menu is intended to open/close a sub-menu, sub-sub-menu, sub-sub-sub-menu etc.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('i.idi').click(function(e) {
    event.stopPropagation();    
    var submenu2 = $(e.target).closest('ul').children('ul li ul.sub-menu');
    var sub = submenu2.context.nextElementSibling;
    var submenu = $(e.target).closest('li').children('ul.sub-menu');
    
    for (let i = 0; i < submenu.length; i++) {
      if (sub.classList.contains("hidden")) {
        var submenu1 = document.querySelectorAll('ul li ul');
        for (let i = 0; i < submenu1.length; i++) {
          if (submenu1[i].classList.contains("hidden")) {} else {
            submenu1[i].classList.remove("block");
            submenu1[i].classList.add("hidden");
          }
        }
        sub.classList.remove("hidden");
        sub.classList.add("block");
      } else {
        var submenu1 = document.querySelectorAll('ul li ul');
        for (let i = 0; i < submenu1.length; i++) {
          if (submenu1[i].classList.contains("hidden")) {} else {
            submenu1[i].classList.remove("block");
            submenu1[i].classList.add("hidden");
          }
        }

        sub.classList.remove("block");
        sub.classList.add("hidden");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Here is the html code

```html
    <nav>
        <ul>
              <li>
                  <a href="">
                      <i class="material-icons idi">home</i>
                  </a>
              </li>
                  <li>
                      <a href="" class="mparent">
                          Default
                      </a>
                      <i class="material-icons idi">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
                      <ul class="sub-menu hidden">
                          <li><a href="">
                                  test subcat
                              </a>                      
                          </li>
                      </ul> 
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

```
 <nav>
    <ul>
       <li>
          <a href="">
              <i class="material-icons idi">home</i>
          </a>
       </li>
       <li>
           <a href="" class="mparent">
              Default
           </a>
           <i class="material-icons idi">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
             <ul class="sub-menu hidden">
                 <li><a href="">
                              test subcat
                      </a>                      
                </li>
            </ul> 
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Here is the css code that can be used.

```
.sub-menu.hidden {
    display: none;
}
.sub-menu.block {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: The question you've linked to is regarding replacing a contextual selector, eg. `$('.child', '.parent')`, with `find()`, eg. `$('.parent').find('.child')`. However, this is not at all relevant to your question as there are no contextual selectors within it. Can you please add all the relevant HTML and CSS to the question so we can see a working example of the problem.

Comment: From the use, I would hazard a guess that `var sub = submenu2.context.nextElementSibling;` -> `var sub = submenu2[0].nextElementSibling;` as .nextElementSibling is expecting a single DOM node, which `[0]` gives you.

Comment: However, there's some other "dodgy" code that it may not be that simple, specifically `.closest('ul').children('ul li ul.sub-menu`) would (a) require `<ul><ul>` which isn't valid html and (b) not find anything as that's not how `.children()` works - it's  `.children().filter(selector)` which won't find the sub li/ul etc.

Comment: So you *may* need:  `var sub = $(e.target).closest('ul')[0].nextElementSibling` (or `$(e.target).closest('ul').next()[0]`

Comment: Tried to add some more html and css code to understand.

Comment: Thank freedomn for the code, tryed it, and i get Uncaught TypeError: sub is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the red-herring that is `submenu2` and use:

```
var sub = $(e.target)[0].nextElementSibling;
```

Code, html as provided and js with the above adjustment, using jquery 3.3.1 (latest for a snippet):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('i.idi').click(function(e) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var sub = $(e.target)[0].nextElementSibling;
    var submenu = $(e.target).closest('li').children('ul.sub-menu');

    for (let i = 0; i < submenu.length; i++) {
      if (sub.classList.contains("hidden")) {
        var submenu1 = document.querySelectorAll('ul li ul');
        for (let i = 0; i < submenu1.length; i++) {
          if (submenu1[i].classList.contains("hidden")) {} else {
            submenu1[i].classList.remove("block");
            submenu1[i].classList.add("hidden");
          }
        }
        sub.classList.remove("hidden");
        sub.classList.add("block");
      } else {
        var submenu1 = document.querySelectorAll('ul li ul');
        for (let i = 0; i < submenu1.length; i++) {
          if (submenu1[i].classList.contains("hidden")) {} else {
            submenu1[i].classList.remove("block");
            submenu1[i].classList.add("hidden");
          }
        }

        sub.classList.remove("block");
        sub.classList.add("hidden");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.sub-menu.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.sub-menu.block {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="">
        <i class="material-icons idi">home</i>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="" class="mparent">Default</a>
      <i class="material-icons idi">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
      <ul class="sub-menu hidden">
        <li><a href="">test subcat</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Your a king freedomn-m ! That work perfectly ! <3 Thank you very much

Comment: This needs more upvotes. Worked like a charm.